# Start Iceweasel/FireFox via the command line with proxy and startpage parameters

Tags: linux, firefox, command-line, proxy, iceweasel

When starting Iceweasel in Debian Linux, I have to manually add a proxy in the network tab options. Is there a way to do it with the command line?

Also, I would like to start Iceweasel on a specific home page.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to add the proxy via terminal but you can open specific `url` using Terminal

```
 firefox [option]
 -browser           Open a browser window.
 -new-window  <url> Open <url> in a new window.
 -new-tab     <url> Open <url> in a new tab.
 -private-window <url> Open <url> in a new private window.
```

example:

```
firefox www.stackoverflow.com  
firefox -new-window www.hackaholic.info
firefox -new-tab www.stackoverflow.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a additional profile in firefox / iceweasel.

1. close iceweasel
2. run `iceweasel -P`
3. set the properties you want for this profile

Now you can start iceweasel with `iceweasel -P <name of your profile>`

Reference Link: [https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles]